# How to select option from dropdown in selenium (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, select, dropdown

I want to write a script for testing dropdown inside the webpage. But, I was unable to do so in selenium using Nodejs. Is there any method to test dropdown in selenium(NodeJs).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**You can create a select class like this and then use method based on your selection.**

```
var SelectWrapper = function(selector) {
    this.webElement = element(selector);
};
SelectWrapper.prototype.getOptions = function() {
    return this.webElement.all(by.tagName('option'));
};
SelectWrapper.prototype.getSelectedOptions = function() {
    return this.webElement.all(by.css('option[selected="selected"]'));
};
SelectWrapper.prototype.selectByValue = function(value) {
    return this.webElement.all(by.css('option[value="' + value + '"]')).click();
};
SelectWrapper.prototype.selectByPartialText = function(text) {
    return this.webElement.all(by.cssContainingText('option', text)).click();
};
SelectWrapper.prototype.selectByText = function(text) {
    return this.webElement.all(by.xpath('option[.="' + text + '"]')).click();
};

module.exports = SelectWrapper;
```

**Usage in test class**

```
var SelectWrapper = require('./select-wrapper.js');
var mySelect = new SelectWrapper(by.id("validSelectTagID"));

describe("Select Wrapper",function(){
    it("Handling the dropdown list",function(){
        browser.get("http://validURL");
        mySelect.selectByText("TextinDrop");
        mySelect.selectByValue("ValueInDrop");
    }) ;
```